# Distinguish between null and missing parameters in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm writing an API. I want to allow a PUT method to update a resource. Below is an example model object representing the resource-

```
var resourceToUpdate = new TestResourceModel() 
    {
        Id = 5
        Name = "testName",
        Description = "description",
        etc...
    }
```

I want a client to be able to PUT to /TestResource/5 to update properties on the resource

Now, say that the client only wants to update property Name, but not description so sends the following request:

```
Name="testNewName"
```

In this case, the resource should be updated so Name is now "testNewName", put Description is still "description"

How do I distinguish this case (in my Controller method), from the case where the client wants to set the Description property to null:

```
Name="testNewName"
Description=
```

as my controller method will look like:

```
[HttpPut]
public ActionResult Index(TestResourceModel model)
{
    //True in both cases
    bool descriptionSet = model.Description == null;
```

Comment: you can null check properties

Answer (score 1):

Well you have to compare the incoming values with the values you want to update.. I mean null is null is null :) 
Alt. set an update flag in your model (bool isUpdate) then only change the values that isn't null.

Comment: I don't think that solves the problem. My point is- that in this case null **isn't** null - there is a distinction between the client POSTing 'Set Description null', and the client POSTing a requet that makes no reference to Description

Comment: Idon't get it.. when u send you model to the view it contains: Id = 5
        Name = "testName" Description = "description" the u change whatever u want and put the model for update. How can the description become null if you haven't changed it?

Comment: This is for an API. So there is no View involved. A request comes straight to the controller from an external client. I want to distinguish between when they send a parameter "Description=" to set description to null, and when they do not include that parameter (indicating they don't want to change it)

Comment: Right sry.. but it's the same thing. Why would you send a "partial" object between client-server. If you always send a "full" object there is no need to compare, you just set the server object same as the incoming client object.