# in WSGI, how to distinguish between blank and missing query param?

Tags: google-app-engine, wsgi

Something like this question:

> [Distinguish between null and missing parameters in ASP.NET MVC4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10241375/distinguish-between-null-and-missing-parameters-in-asp-net-mvc4)

...except for WSGI.   How can I distinguish between a "no value" query param, and a query param that is not present.

According to [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass#Request_arguments), this code:

```
value = self.request.get('n')
```

..returns the empty string when the query parameter is not present. 
What will it return if the query param is present but has no value, eq a query string of `?n` ?

I am trying to test this, but honestly, I'm having trouble with GAE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As specified in [that doc you linked](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass#Request_get):

> get(argument_name, default_value='')

Specify the `default_value` parameter:

```
self.request.get('n', None)
```

will return `None` if the parameter `n` isn't present (e.g. `?foo=bar`). If the parameter is present but doesn't specify a value, you'll get an empty string (e.g. `?n=&foo=bar`).

Comment: Thanks. Seems like the default behavior is dumb. Using the defaults, it is not possible to distinguish between a query string param that is present and set to nothing, and a query string param that is not present at all. Should always use the `None` default I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend against using the `self.request.get` interface. It's a thin wrapper around the `request` object, and at this point is mostly there for compatibility with webapp1 apps. Instead, use `self.request.GET` for query parameters and `self.request.POST` for request body parameters. These both act as dictionaries, so indexing them like `self.request.GET['foo']` will raise a `KeyError` if the key does not exist, while calling `self.request.GET.get('foo', default)` will return `default` if the key does not exist.